# How can I publish mulitple content to dotCMS through script

Tags: dotcms

As I am new to dotCMS, just wondering is it support any script through which I can upload/publish my multiple contents(i.e well structured directory) as whole. For example I have multiple text files with contents to publish how can i do this in one shot ?

I know it support dynamic content page, but seems that works on already created content/page.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1. You can either put all the content in an Excel file and use the "import content" option of the "Add new Content" button in the dotCMS admin "Content" tab. To know what the Excel structure should be, first download a piece of the content you plan to upload by clicking on the "Export button in the same page".

[image]
[image]

2. The second way is to use the Restfull content API. Check the [documentation](https://dotcms.com/docs/latest/rest-api) on how to use it.